# How to run a maven plugin without including it in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I want to run the following plugin, but without having to include it into my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Reason: I have a project that I build and deploy from `gitlab-ci`. I want to create a job stage that checks for new version regarding my `pom.xml` definition. But the check should not be part of the usual project, thus I'm trying to include this version check plugin only in the gitlab stage, and not in my code.

Is that possible to use a maven plugin on the fly *onto* another pom?

Comment: Use maven profiles. Run with a different profile locally and on gitlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem.

You can run

`mvn versions:update-parent`

for e.g. the `update-parent` goal.

or if you want a fixed version, you can run

`mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.11.0:update-parent`